# Error on INSERT statement: "VALUE is not valid at this position"

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

> VALUE is not valid at this position

The error is on `VALUES` within the `INSERT` statement. It states it is not supported within this version. Does that mean i require an update or is my syntax wrong?

```
create schema Cleudo;
USE CLEUDO;

create table Victim(
   Vic_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Vic_Title VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   Vic_Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   Vic_Room VARCHAR(30) NULL,
   Vic_TOD VARCHAR(5) NULL,
   Vic_Weapon VARCHAR(30) NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( VIC_ID )
);

INSERT INTO Victim VALUES ('Miss','Scarlet','Library','10:45','candle-Stick');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because the number of columns are not the same, so you need to change your query to this:

```
INSERT INTO Victim(Vic_Title,Vic_Name,Vic_Room,Vic_TOD,Vic_Weapon) VALUES ('Miss','Scarlet','Library','10:45','candle-Stick');
```

In case you want to specify the Vic_ID value you can try this query below instead:

```
INSERT INTO Victim VALUES (NULL,'Miss','Scarlet','Library','10:45','candle-Stick')
```

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, I get the following error:

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

This is happening because you are not giving a value to table `Vic_ID` (which makes sense, because it is auto-incremented). To avoid the error, you need to enumerate the target columns, like so:

```
INSERT INTO Victim (Vic_Title, Vic_Name, Vic_Room, Vic_TOD, Vic_Weapon)
VALUES ('Miss','Scarlet','Library','10:45','candle-Stick');
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2a0184c159a6920dc083ff4d11670ad1)**